# Unable to add new row in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, table

I'm trying to create new rows to my table, in my lightning component, in this way:

```
insertNewRow : function(component, event, helper) {
    [
        ["tr"],
        ["td"]
    ],
    function(components, status, errorMessage){
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var tr = components[0];
            var td = components[1];
            // set the body of the ui:message to be the ui:outputText
            tr.set("v.body", td);
        }
        else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            // Show offline error
        }
        else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            // Show error message
        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. 
For completeness, here it is the code of the table:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <lightning:input label=" " name="documentName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <lightning:select name="select" label=" " required="true">
                        <option value="TBD" text="TBD"></option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <lightning:select name="select" label=" " required="true">
                        <option value="TBD" text="TBD"></option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td><lightning:input type="file" label=" " name="file" multiple="true" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" onchange=""/></td>
                <td><lightning:button label="" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left"/></td>
            </tr>
            {!v.body}
    </table>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Nuovo" iconName="utility:new" iconPosition="left" onclick="{c.insertNewRow}"/>
```

Finally, this is the error message shown:

```
Uncaught Action failed: lightning:button$controller$handleClick [d.run is not a function]
throws at https:/dev-ed.lightning.force./com/auraFW/javascript/zsWZWPmRKjQt6GsG2UtCYg/aura_prod.js:2:15
handleClick()@components/lightning/button.js:2:455
{anonymous}()@components/aura/html.js:6:222
Object.dispatchAction()@components/aura/html.js:6:205
Object.domEventHandler()@components/aura/html.js:6:149
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Why not make each row an instance of an object, and iterate over them using `aura:iteration`?

Comment: I don't get it, please explain with more details.

Comment: In your example you are dynamically changing the DOM by inserting the HTML tags. I suggested that you wrap your columns into a javascript object, so you can have a list and iterate over it. So when you add a line, you will actually push a new instance of that object into the list that is being handled by your page. I've wrote about Lightning Components and my example covers the tag I mentioned (here: https://medium.com/@renatoliveira/user-activation-example-c52833767653).

Comment: If you truly need to be able to create any number of new components, use `$A.createComponent`, you can easily create new components in your client side controller and push them to the `v.body` component on your page...not sure exactly what approach you're trying to take here, but it doesn't look orthodox. See here for more: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: I used it... but it seems that this method doesn't create pure html elements but only the lightning ones.

Comment: you are using slds classes for your html and lightning inputs already, if you just break them into components, the effect will be the same...

Comment: Right! I'll try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create `aura:html` components dynamically you want to do like this

```
    insertNewRow : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponents([
         ["aura:html", {"tag":"tr", "HTMLAttributes":{"id":"mytr"}],
         ["aura:html", {"tag":"td", "HTMLAttributes":{"id":"mytd"}]
    ],
    function(components, status, errorMessage){
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var tr = components[0];
            var td = components[1];
            // set the body of the ui:message to be the ui:outputText
            tr.set("v.body", td);
        }
        else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            // Show offline error
        }
        else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            // Show error message
        }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: The answer is incomplete, but you gave me the right hint :) You forgot to add the tr to the parent component. In your way it doesn't show anything. Anyway, I accept your answer. Please, vote my question.

Comment: Yup ,I accept that,I just said how to define `aura:html`   components dynamically.